# Converting a "RC" format to "A1" for use in a conditional format

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I've written code  which adds a conditional condition - however I want to reuse the code and what I find is I need to change the row numbers in the condition based on the starting row of the range I apply the conditions to

So here's my code  with inline some comments on the problem

```
Dim RG As Range, fmtc As FormatCondition
Set RG = WS.UsedRange
```

I want the range to start at row 3  - this was row 2

```
Set RG = Range(RG.Cells(3, 1), RG.Cells(RG.Rows.Count, RG.Columns.Count))
```

But that now means I must increment the numbers in the following (ie 2 to 3 and 3 to 4)

```
Set fmtc = RG.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$f2<>$f3")
```

so that it becomes

```
Set fmtc = RG.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$f3<>$f4")
```

But this varies based on the rg.row
If Excel supported it I would use the following as it is unaffected by the row that RG starts on

```
Set fmtc = RG.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, FormulaRC1:="=RC6<>R[+1]C6")
```

I have considered , written and tested the following

```
Function RCtoFN(Argrg As Range, rc As String) As String
Dim formsafe As String, rg As Range
Set rg = Argrg.Cells(1, 1)
formsafe = rg.Formula
rg.FormulaR1C1 = rc
RCtoFN = rg.Formula
rg.Formula = formsafe
End Function

Set fmtc = RG.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=RCtoFN(rg,"=RC6<>R[+1]C6"))
```

It appears to be working but I dislike this due to the need to save the formulae in rg.cells(1,1) and restore it which can trigger recalculations and possibly errors with the result of lost data

So my question is does anyone have a method to do this conversion from RC format to normal format?

As a explanation of what I am doing , this is so that the conditional format draws a line between all cells of the rows when the change of value in one column changes from one row to the next

```
With fmtc.Borders(xlBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = -16777024
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ross

You can convert from R1C1 to A1, or vice versa, using the `ConvertFormula` function but I'm not sure you actually need it.

This will work as the formula can use either A1 or R1C1 notation.

```vb
Set fmtc = RG.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=RC6<>R[+1]C6")
```

Comment: Well - I made that much more complex ... I did try it before I did this - but I got an error - so I gave up - I probably had the syntax wrong the first time - I just removed my function and sure enough it works